# Fetch data in IE8 using pywin32

Tags: python, internet-explorer-8, full-text-search, pywin32, python-2.5

---

I've been trying to fetch data using pywin32(Internet Explorer) but can't find anything good, Basically I want to fetch the data from the current source of IE PAGE for example : if http://whoer.net is opened then I would like to fetch the country or if the country is this then do this the "If" statement work, but my main concept for this post is to get the data using pywin32(Python2.5) or either print the data on the python console window or so. Currently using:

```
import pythoncom
from win32com.client import *

pythoncom.CoInitialize()
ie = Dispatch("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate2("http://whoer.net")
ie.Visible = True
```

Please Let me know how to search or find any data in that or print it.Thanks

EDIT : Note that I don't want to use any other modules/library(like urllib/mechanize) I want it on IE.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you don't want to use any external modules, however, you might have a better time of it using something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to deal with the content of the web page, or if you wanted to go lower level you could even use the built-in [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html).

If you insist on using just win32com, the topic is far too complex to give in an answer.  My recommendation is to look at the source code for [PAMIE](http://pamie.sourceforge.net/).  It's bit old, but it's a pure Python module that does IE browser automation using (for the most part) just win32com, and as far as I know the only other dependenciese are on built-in modules.  It should work just fine on Python 2.5, as well.